# How to Stop SpeakAsync if another message were about to speak out?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech, speech-to-text

I'm trying to create a web page with speech recognition using c# as my code behind.
Please help me because I want to know how may I stop a SpeakAsync to deliver the full message when another message started to speak.

pseudocode like this

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ss.SpeakAsync(CurrentStop); // it means if there is a current message it should stop before delivering the next line
        ss.SpeakAsync("Phrase and Sentence");
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ss.SpeakAsync(CurrentStop);
        ss.SpeakAsync("Phrase is a group of words without a complete thought.");
    }
```

please help me. It's my first time to use c# as well as system.speech

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `GetCurrentlySpokenPrompt` and `SpeakAsyncCancel` methods to cancel the current prompt:

```
var current = ss.GetCurrentlySpokenPrompt();

if (current != null)
    ss.SpeakAsyncCancel(current);
```

---

**Full Example**

```
var ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();

ss.SpeakAsync("This is a test.");

Thread.Sleep(300);

var current = ss.GetCurrentlySpokenPrompt();

if (current != null)
    ss.SpeakAsyncCancel(current);

ss.SpeakAsync("Goodbye.");
```

Comment: hello,,  thank you for your response, but is there a way for me to use `var current = ss.GetCurrentlySpokenPrompt();` for global?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "for global".

Comment: I tried declaring `Prompt current;` as global variable then on my methods i used like `current = ss.GetCurrentlySpokenPrompt();` but it's not working. maybe I'm wrong , what should I replace to `var` to make it global . Thank you !

Comment: when I say global, I mean public . sorry for that. 
ahm. your example is working but what I'm trying to do is like this `public partial class WebForm2
    {
        var current = ss.GetCurrentlySpokenPrompt(); //but it gives me error on this because I cannot use var outside a method, I'm trying to figure out what should I use here instead of var             Button2_Click()
        { if (current != null)
                ss.SpeakAsyncCancel(current);
      ss.SpeakAsync("Goodbye.");
        }
        Button1_Click()
        {  ss.SpeakAsync("This is a test.");
            Thread.Sleep(300); }`

Comment: You can make a property: `protected Prompt Current { get { return ss.GetCurrentlySpokenPrompt(); } }`